# Get minDate, maxDate and defaultDate from datetimepicker jQuery

Tags: jquery

I build datetimepicker that already set minDate, maxDate and defaultDate as image below. It's work for pickup date. I want to get minDate, maxDate and defaultDate from datetimepicker on **function onChangeOpeningDateEdit()**, but I don't know how to. Could you suggest me, please?

[image]
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#date_opening_edit').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD-MMM-YYYY",
        minDate: getMinDateFunction(),
        maxDate: getMaxDateFunction(),
        defaultDate: null,
    });

    function getMaxDateFunction() {
        var d = new Date();
        var y = d.getFullYear();
        var m = d.getMonth();
        var da = d.getDate() + 10;
        var h = d.getHours();
        var mi = d.getMinutes();
        var se = d.getSeconds();
        var mDate = new Date(y, m, da, h, mi, se);
        return mDate;
    };

    function getMinDateFunction() {
        var d = new Date();
        var y = d.getFullYear();
        var m = d.getMonth();
        var da = d.getDate() - 10;
        var h = d.getHours();
        var mi = d.getMinutes();
        var se = d.getSeconds();
        var mDate = new Date(y, m, da, h, mi, se);
        return mDate;
    };

    function onChangeOpeningDateEdit() {
        var minDate = $("#date_opening_edit").datetimepicker("minDate"); // I want to get minDate from datetimepicker, but I don't know how to.
        alert(minDate);
    }
</script>

<div class='input-group date ' id='date_opening_edit'>
    <input type='text' id="txt_opening_date_edit" class="form-control" data-format="DD-MMM-YYYY"
        placeholder="Opening Date" runat="server" onblur="onChangeOpeningDateEdit()" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: so you calculate the dates then append them to the datepicker then you want to get the dates back from the date picker, yes?

Comment: why not simply store the dates when you create them?

Comment: @madalinivascu, Yes.

Comment: Which datepicker plugin you are using?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM, Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker v4.17.47, http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

Datepicker options can be accessed via **data** attribute

```
function onChangeOpeningDateEdit() {
    var d = planned_element //$("#date_opening_edit")
    var default_date = d.data('DateTimePicker').defaultDate()
    var min_date = d.data('DateTimePicker').minDate()
    var max_date = d.data('DateTimePicker').maxDate()
    alert("minDate:" + min_date +" maxDate:" + max_date + " defaultDate:"+ default_date);
}
```